# Finding something specific from HTML

Tags: c#, .net, html-parsing

I have a string that looks like this:

```
<br /><br />\n\n<p><font size=\"4\" face=\"Courier New\"> TSX Symbol Changes -December    
17th - December 21st</font><br>
```

What i need to do is pull out TSX Symbol Changes -December 17th - December 21st. I've read on various other posts that Regex.IsMatch works for this situation but the problem I have is that December 17th - 21st will change every week (i.e. when i run my code next week the name will change to TSX Symbol Changes - December 24th - December 28th). So is there anyway I can look for just TSX Symbol Changes and once thats found retrieve the dates after it as well?

Comment: Use [`Html Agility Pack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) if you need to parse html.

Comment: If you are sure "TSX" is always at the start of your string, simply find the index of that substring in the string and count forward to the first "</" which you know is the start of HTML. You can then grab the substring with the start and end indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code bleow.

```
    var str1 = "<br /><br />\n\n<p><font size=\"4\" face=\"Courier New\"> TSX Symbol Changes -December 17th - December 21st</font><br>";
    var str2 = str1.Substring(str1.IndexOf("TSX Symbol Changes")).Replace("</font><br>","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Html Agility Pack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) if you need to parse html.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);  // this is your string

string wordToFind = "TSX Symbol Changes -";
var fontTSX = doc.DocumentNode.Elements("font")
    .FirstOrDefault(f => f.InnerText.Contains(wordToFind));
if (fontTSX != null)
{
    string innerText = fontTSX.InnerText.Trim();
    innerText = innerText.Substring(innerText.IndexOf(wordToFind) + wordToFind.Length);
    String[] words = innerText.Split();
    String monthName = words.First();
    var monthInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames
        .Select((mn, i) => new{ MonthName = mn, Value = i+1 })
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.MonthName.Equals(monthName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    if (monthInfo != null)
    {
        int month = monthInfo.Value;
        int day = int.MinValue;
        // now extract your range
        IEnumerable<int> days = words
            .Where(w => w.Length >= 2 && int.TryParse(w.Substring(0, 2), out day))
            .Select(w => day)
            .Take(2);
        if(days.Count() == 2)
        {
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, month, days.ElementAt(0));
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, month, days.ElementAt(1));
        }
    }
```